# How to implement in-place std::string substr

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, iterator

I am trying to write a function that will get the substring of a string, but modifying it in-place rather than making duplicates.

The C-ish way:

```c
memmove((void*)&str[0], (const void*)&str[start], sizeof(char)*count);
str.resize(count);
```

As close to C++11 as I know how to code:

```cpp
auto write_it=str.begin();
for(auto read_it=str.begin()+start;read_it!=str.begin()+start+count;read_it++)
{
    *write_it=*read_it;
    write_it++;
}
str.resize(count);
```

Which of these is theoretically faster? My hunch was `memmove()`, but that creates a buffer under the hood anyway, so that might actually hurt us in the end.

Are either of these portable? I am not sure if my modification of the string is guaranteed not to invalidate my iterators. Edit: According to [Does moving characters into string invalidate iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883312/does-moving-characters-into-string-invalidate-iterators) my iterator approach is safe. But is it performant? The only reason I care is that I am writing code that will be called by other users so it needs to at least be reasonably performant.

I am incredibly surprised there is no discussion of this anywhere I've looked.

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you believe `memmove` "creates a buffer under the hood anyway"? That's not true.

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: I appear to have been incorrect about memmove, I was confused by this. cplusplus.com: "Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed by source to the memory block pointed by destination. Copying takes place as if an intermediate buffer were used, allowing the destination and source to overlap."

Comment: `str.erase(str.begin() + start + count, str.end()); str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin() + start);` should do the trick. That second `erase` call is `memmove`, essentially.

Comment: Is the erase method faster, or about as performant as my iterator approach?

Comment: @user2123677 In the first instance it’s vastly (!) more readable. In the second instance, there’s no reason why it shouldn’t be at least as efficient, since it works with a more constrained interface so, at worst, it could be implemented by the iterator method under the hood. At best it uses something better. That said, I’d be tempted to switch the two `erase` operations: `str.erase(0, start); str.erase(count);`

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Removing the suffix first is faster, especially for a short substring near the beginning of a long string.